# How to use DbContext inside xUnit Test project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have added a test project for my core 1.0 application. Inside of which I have repositories that use dbContext in constructor.

How can I get access to this dbContext inside of test project and inject it properly?

This is my ApplicationDbContext class:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my unit test method:

```
[Fact]
public void ProductsGetAll()
        {
        //here i need to get acces to dbContext and inject it below

            ProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository(dbContext);
            CategoryRepository categoryRepository = new CategoryRepository(dbContext);
            ProductController productController = new ProductController(productRepository, categoryRepository);
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I have added context in the test constructor:

```
ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public UnitTest1()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
             .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "FakeDatabase")
             .Options;

        dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
    }
```

and my test method:

```
    [Fact]
        public void ProductsGetAll()
        {
            IProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository(dbContext);
            ICategoryRepository categoryRepository = new CategoryRepository(dbContext);
            ProductController productController = new ProductController(productRepository, categoryRepository);

            var result = productController.List("Pizza");

            var contentResult = result as ViewResult;
            var final = contentResult != null;
            Assert.False(final, "Shouldnt be null");
```

but now I have an error:

```
Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: What exactly are you testing?  If it's `ProductController` then you should mock the repositories for unit test.  On the other hand if you're doing an integration test then you'll have to point at an actually DB and if you want that to work on local machines and build servers you'll likely want to write code to generate a temp db to use.  The alternative is to keep connection string info in your config to point at the location of local and build server DBs to test against.  But then you'll have to be careful about tests mutating the DB and what that means when the tests are run multiple times.

Comment: Usually what you do in unit tests is that you create a mock of your database as you do not want to test the database in your unit tests that is what your integration tests is used for. If you mock your database and entities you can simply have a InitializeTest method that initialises your testcontext and mock entities. I recommend using Moq

Comment: did you consider using a in memory database for testing and injecting a context using this in your test? see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

Comment: is there any option to use only one context for every test method?

Comment: Unit tests should not be dealing with data (e.g. `DbContext`). That is an internal aspect and does not pertain to logic. It is your repositories that should be mocked and that can be done with interfaces.

Comment: @JuanR I have updated my question, please have an eye

Comment: @ChrisK. I assume the context was null?

Comment: @ChrisK: Nothing has changed. You should not be relying on databases or contexts. Look at the bottom of Win's answer below. Mock the repositories instead.

Comment: @nozzleman not really, i just wanted to make a basic test to check if it works

Comment: and i have no idea how to use @Win code

Comment: Replace `IProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository(dbContext);` with `var mockProductRepository = new Mock<IProductRepository>();`, then configure the mock to return the data you need to conduct your tests, as indicated in Win's answer.

Comment: @ChrisK. did you manage to get it working by now?

Comment: @nozzleman yes, i have used InMemory and seed database with some test data

Comment: Then feel free to accept one of the answers or provide you own ;)

Answer (score 3):

I create an [interface](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Data/AppDbContext.cs), and place all DbSets inside it.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : 
   IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>,  IDbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    ...
}

public interface IDbContext
{
   DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

My [repository](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Repositories/Users/UserRepository.cs) depends on an interface instead of DbContext.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
   private readonly IDbContext _context;

   public UserRepository(IDbContext context)
   {
      _context = context;
   }
}
```

Then, I mock IDbContext like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Tests/Asp.Repositories.Tests/Users/UserRepositoryTests.cs#L69) instead of actual ApplicationDbContext.

```
var mockSet = MockHelper.GetMockDbSet(_users);
var mockDbContext = new Mock<IDbContext>();
mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.Users).Returns(mockSet.Object);
varmockDbContext = mockDbContext.Object;
```

### Update

Based on question, you are trying to mock the repositories.

If so, I suggest you to create ***interfaces*** and implement those interfaces. Then inject those interfaces to the constructor instead of injecting concrete classes. E.g. use `IProductRepository` instead of `ProductRepository`.

You can then simply mock like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Tests/Asp.Web.Tests/Controllers/UsersControllerTests.cs#L95) -

```
var mockProductRepository = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
mockProductRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAllProductsAsync()).ReturnsAsync(_products);
var productController = new ProductController(mockProductRepository.Object,...);
```

Comment: This would certainly work but I think he should be mocking the repositories instead.

Comment: @JuanR Good catch; I did not notice that OP is trying to mock repositories. I updated the answer.

Comment: The question is still valid - repositories provide an abstraction to the db context but someone might want to mock that in order to unit test the repository code

Answer (score 2):

Im not a .NET Core Person, but I guess you could try using an In-Memory Database for Unit Testing.

In older Versions of EntityFramework, you could have used [Effort](http://entityframework-effort.net/?z=codeplex), EF Core seems to have solved this oob. Im not sure if this would work right away, since I have never tried this out by myself (again, not a .net core guy), but you should get started like that:

First, add the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory`.
Then Create the Context and configure it to use the In-Memory-DB

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "pick_or_generate_a_unique_name_here")
    .Options;

var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
```

Finally, inject the context into your repositories and use them in your tests

```
var productRepository = new ProductRepository(context);
var categoryRepository = new CategoryRepository(context);
var productController = new ProductController(productRepository, categoryRepository);
```

See this [blogpost](https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-entity-framework-core-in-memory-database-asp-net-core) and [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) for further information.

Comment: is there any option to use only one context for every test method?

Comment: I don't know XUnit, but you could simple instaciate a new one using a different name in some kind of setup method (in xunit this seems to be the ctor)

Comment: @ChrisK.: In xUnit, setup is handled via the constructor, so setup your context there and save it to a private field.

Comment: Microsoft now discourages using the EntityFramework database. You could use a SQLite in-memory database instead (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/#approach-3-the-ef-core-in-memory-database)